# ClosedXML read from excel file

Tags: closedxml

I have an excel file. I simply need a cell value. I am having a hard time finding documentation on this. I have done ClosedXML before where I write date to an excel file but not where I read from it.

```
      const string fileName = 
                    @"C:\Folder1\Form.xlsx";

        // Retrieve the value in cell A1.
         var workbook1 = new XLWorkbook(fileName);
         var ws1 = workbook1.Worksheet(1);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities to get a cell and its value depending on the data type:

```
var cell = ws.Cell("A1");
var cell = ws.Cell(1, 2);                 // row 1, column 2

object result = cell.Value;
string result = cell.Value.ToString();    // if you want to get text
string result = cell.GetValue<string>();  // also for text
int result = cell.GetValue<int>();        // for integer numbers
```

And more for other datatypes.